# TypeScript click event handler

Tags: typescript, jquery-events

In Javascript the following code works as expected:

```
$("#field").click(eventHandler);

function eventHander() {
  invokeClassMethod();
  // do other stuff
}
```

I tried this in Typescript and I get an error because it appears the context of "this" has changed to something that's not my class.

```
$("#field").click(this.eventHandler);

eventHandler() {
  this.invokeClassMethod();
  // do other stuff
}
```

gives me an error because "invokeClassMethod" is undefined.

I'm new to Typescript so can somebody please tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah ok the answer was simple and really comes down to me being unfamiliar with Javascript features... here's how I got it to work:

```
$("#field").click(() => this.eventHandler());
```

using bind() also works:

```
$("#field").click(this.eventHandler.bind(this));
```

and jQuery proxy works:

```
$("#field").click($.proxy(this.eventHandler, this));
```